# How to implement a Higher Order Component using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, react-router-dom, higher-order-components

I am trying to implement a Higher Order Component (HOC) in TypeScript so that I can pass my `ErrorBoundary` as a parameter to the HOC and then the HOC returns the current location of the user so that I can use it in my `ErrorBoundary` component.

ErrorBoundary:

```
import React from "react";

interface ErrorBoundaryProps {
  fallback: React.ReactNode;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  location: {
    pathname: string;
  };
}

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<ErrorBoundaryProps> {
  state = { hasError: false };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(previousProps: ErrorBoundaryProps) {
    if (previousProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
      this.setState({ hasError: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return this.props.fallback;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

WithRouter HOC:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function WithRouter(OriginalComponent: React.ComponentType) {
  const NewComponent = (props: any) => {
    const location = useLocation();

    return <OriginalComponent {...props} location={location} />;
  };
  return NewComponent;
}
```

Apparently the TypeScript compiler is not happy and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've just tried to experiment with different implementations but nothing seems to be working.

If this helps, this is what works in JavaScript:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function WithRouter(OriginalComponent) {
  const NewComponent = (props) => {
    const location = useLocation();

    return <OriginalComponent location={location} {...props} />;
  };
  return NewComponent;
}
```

But I'm just struggling to convert it to TypeScript.

Comment: When you say "the TypeScript compiler is not happy," what error is it showing?

Comment: It’s highlighting the part where I return the original component and it’s saying unreachable code detected.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify what the issue or problem is. If there is an error, please include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace, see [mcve]. See also [Help/How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for further tips to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: On this line: return <OriginalComponent {...props} location={location}/>, I am getting this error: "'OriginalComponent' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof OriginalComponent'?" Also, on this part: location={location}/>, it is saying unreachable code detected as well as "Cannot assign to 'location' because it is a constant."